# Can any one help me to learn reverse url in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have a menu in my project and I want to call different Views.

For example, if I have a menu like:

> home | about Us | Contact-Us

If I click on home it will call home view successful and then when I click again on home it takes to home/home or when I click on about-us it will take me to home/about-us

Every call (click) on menu will increase home/about-us/home........ like this.

How can I correct 'Url' patterns? I read the documentation but I did not get any idea or solution.

Comment: Since you haven't shown any code, no we cannot help you.

Comment: You should show your an example url/view that you are using

Comment: from . views import login,home,Aboutus
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',login,name='login'),
    url(r'^Aboutus/$',Aboutus),
    url(r'^home/$',home,name='home'),

Comment: from . views import login,home,Aboutus
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',login,name='login'),
    url(r'^Aboutus/$',Aboutus),
    url(r'^home/$',home,name='home'),
]

#######i views ##########
def home(request):
 return render(request,"Home.html")

def Aboutus(request):
 return render(request,"Aboutus.html")
################ Template ############
i create menu for navigation 
 <li class="first expanded"><a href="-listing.html">Candidates</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="Aboutus">Aboutus</a></li>
          <li><a href="home">home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a URL defined for the About page that looks like this:

```
url(r'^about/$', 'website.views.about', name='about'),
```

You can reverse a URL in a template like this

```
{% url 'about' %}
```

Or you can reverse a URL in your views.py like this

```
return redirect(reverse('about'))
```

Comment: Sir... how can i add this {% url 'about' %} into my hyperlink tag ??
like this ?? <a src='{% url 'about' %}'> Aboutus </a>

Comment: Sir... how can i add this {% url 'about' %} into my hyperlink tag ??
like this ?? <a href='{% url 'about' %}'> Aboutus </a>

Comment: <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>